# Can't access to HTML elements with Selenium (python)

Tags: python, selenium, modal-dialog, bots

I'm new in python scripting. I'm trying to develop a bot that can access websites and work on it with Selenium.

I can do basics things like enter text in a search bar but I am blocked with a popup.
I try to access the popup element but I can't. It seems the element I want to reach are on a "modal" popup.

[image: Element I want to access]

I have tried many things, I can access to the "modal"popup:

```
popup = self.__driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='modal']")
```

but I can't access to any element right under the revious one:

```
element = self.__driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='region-modal-right-panel']")
```

Can somebody help me with this problem? Thank you in advance for your help!!
If my explanations wasn't clear, do not hesitate to ask for mor details.

EDIT: link to the popup: https://app.libertex.com/products/currency/EURUSD/#modal_newInvest_EURUSD

Comment: Can you post the error you get? Also are you using implicitly_wait ??

Comment: The error was the following:
No ellement found for xpath "//div[@id='region-modal-right-panel']"

I don't use implicitly_wait for the moment, I've tried with a "simple" time.sleep" to be sure the popup was available but it doesn't work.